# Is $K\times K$ in Turing machines semidecidable?

Tags: automata, turing-machines, finite-automata

Classify as decidable, not decidable but semi-decidable, or nondecidable, this set: $K\times K$, the cartesian product.

$K$ is the set of words that halts with an input on Turing machine.

For example,

```
input y{
execute mx(y)
halt
}
```

If $Y$ belongs to $K$ it's going to halt.
I know $K$ is not decidable but I don't know if $K\times K$ is semi decidable or not.

Comment: Are we considering some fixed Turing machine here — i.e. $K$ is the set of $y$ s.t. machine $M$ halts on input $y$, for some fixed $M$, or alternatively is $K$ the set of duples $(M,y)$ s.t. $M$ halts on $y$? In any case at first sight I think that $K^{2}$ is going to be nonrecursive, r.e. that is semidecidable but not decidable, as it apparently is reducible to $K$ and vice-versa.

Comment: could you explain it like you would for a "stupid person" (me) this part in an answer?
 In any case at first sight I think that K2K2 is going to be nonrecursive, r.e. that is semidecidable but not decidable, as it apparently is reducible to KK and vice-versa @wet

Comment: Yes, but tell me what you don't understand, so I can see how to explain it appropriately.

Comment: what means nonrecursive on those problems? and how would you "program" this like I did with input y etc..? @wet

Comment: By "nonrecursive, r.e." I meant not decidable, but semidecidable. Do you *need* the answer in pseudocode? Do you know why is $K$ not decidable, but semidecidable? $K\times K$ will not be decidable, because if we had a program that decides it, we could use this program to decide $K$ — can you see why/how?

Comment: yes, I could see why it's not decidable but wasn't sure about why does it became semidecidable, thank you

Comment: Don't reask a question. Ever. Edit the first question and add the extras there (But not this time for I deleted the earlier version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a program that decides $K\times K$, e.g.

```
# Decider for K times K
def F(‹x,y›):
    if x in K and Y in K:
        return True
    else: return False

input = ‹x,y›
print(F(input))
```

Then we can use this program to decide $K$:

```
input = x
print(F(‹input,input›))
```